# Create a new column in Rstudio based on a existing column

Tags: r

I need your help for Rstudio.

I need to create a new column named "Posizione" in this database which is based on Regione name.
Where Regione is "Lombardia or Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Posizionamento" will be "Nord".
Where Regione is "Lazio", "Posizionamento" will be "Centro".
Where Regione is "Sicilia", "Posizionamento" will be "Sud".

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
nord <- c('LOMBARDIA', 'FRIULI-VENEZIA GIULIA')
centro <- c('LAZIO')
sud <- c('SICILIA')

df$Posizione <- ifelse(df$Regione %in% nord, 'NORD',
                       ifelse(df$Regione %in% centro, 'CENTRO',
                              ifelse(df$Regione %in% sud, 'SUD', NA)))
```

Basically, using another `ifelse` function as the `else` argument of the previous one.

In case you have other regions you can just add them in the `nord`, `centro` and `sud` vectors in the way you wish them to be cathegorized.